# Routing 2 public IP ranges on 2 bridges

Tags: linux, debian, routing, linux-networking, proxmox

I've set up a new Proxmox 8 server, and I'm struggling to get my networking set up correctly. A normal bridge interface with a single IP range is easy enough, but I can't seem to get my 2 IP ranges to route correctly when using 2 bridges.

Background:

- The Proxmox host has a single physical interface, `eno1`, which plugs directly into my hosting provider's switch
- My hosting provider has given me 2 IP ranges.

  - 129.212.157.200/29 (Gateway is 129.212.157.201)
  - 129.212.175.24/29 (Gateway is 129.212.175.25)
- I have created two bridges, `vmbr0` and `vmbr1`. This is to provide layer 2 isolation, since I don't entirely trust the VMs on `vmbr1`, since a third-party vendor has root access to them.
- The primary IP address to access the Proxmox server should be 129.212.157.202.

My understanding is that this situation requires a routed configuration. However, this is where things start to fall apart.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` config looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 129.212.157.202/29
    gateway 129.212.157.201

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
    bridge-ports none
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
    bridge-ports none
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

Ideally, I would like to mix-and-match IPs from both IP ranges on both `vmbr0` and `vmbr1`. In other words, I don't want one IP range to be assigned exclusively to `vmbr0` and the other IP range to be assigned exclusively to `vmbr1`.

I have manually added the following routes using `ip ro`:

```
default via 129.212.157.201 dev eno1 proto kernel onlink
129.212.157.200/29 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 129.212.157.202
129.212.175.24/29 via 129.212.175.25 dev eno1
129.212.175.25 dev eno1 scope link
```

Now, I have tried to create a VM and bound the virtual NIC to `vmbr0`, and I've also tried `vmbr1`. For both of these combinations, I have tried configuring the VM with IPs from both the 129.212.157.200/29 range as well as from the 129.212.175.24/29 range, using the gateways 129.212.157.201 and 129.212.175.25 respectively. No matter what combination of vmbr and IP address I use for the VM, I can't seem to get connectivity. I can't even ping the gateway IP from within the VM.

For comparison, and to test that the two IP ranges are in fact routable via the provided gateways, I have successfully set up a simple bridged implementation with a single vmbr0 per the Proxmox documentation, and that works fine, for both IP ranges and both gateways. Things only seem to fall apart when I switch to the routed approach.

I've also confirmed that Proxy ARP and IP Forwarding are both enabled on the Proxmox host.

To me, this looks like a routing issue on the Proxmox host, but for the life of me I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

As far as I can tell, I haven't configured anything special in terms of firewall rules. I do have the firewall enabled at the datacentre level, the host level, and the VM level. I have tried turning off firewalling at the host and VM level, but that also doesn't seem to make a difference.

One suggestion that has been made is to implement NAT, but I don't see why that would be necessary, since each of the VMs will only have a public IP, and no private IP ranges.

Comment: You don't seem to know how you should configure things for just one bridge and IP range. If you want a VM to use the .201 as the gateway, you need a bridge**d** setup. Otherwise, you probably need to have e.g. .202 with `/32` on the physical NIC (with a host route to .201), then have .203/29 on the bridge and .204/29 or so on the VM with .203 being its default gateway. (Certainly you'd then need to make sure the VM host works as a gateway properly, in terms of sysctl and firewall and so on.) ProxyARP might be an alternative, but there's no way to tell if you have done it right.

Comment: `Ideally, I would like to mix-and-match IPs from both IP ranges` if you insist in causing more trouble to yourself, it would probably mean you need /32 and host routes everywhere (a.k.a. p2p topology).

Comment: With that said, by using /32 everywhere you can probably use a private IP on the bridge / as the default gateway of the VMs, which save you two public IPs (in total) from being "wasted". (Might even avoid triggering some RP filter issue, idk.)

Comment: you probably already know this, but make sure IPv6 if off

Comment: This looks like policy-based routing problem. Also having to do ARP proxy and its routing at the same time makes the problem a bit more complex than could have been.  Better forget for now about mix-and-match. And indeed using /29 loses 2 or 3 addresses: thje zero, the broadcast and an IP for proxmox as gateway (though this one could be recovered using some tweaks requiring unusual routing configuration on clients in vmbr1). Else /32 as told could be used everywhere to avoid losing these addresses, but that looks more difficult to manage later.

Comment: Actually proxmox doesn't use its address as gateway, but almost the same, for ARP request: if the 2nd router uses Strict Reverse Path Forwarding, it might ignore an ARP request from the wrong LAN (Linux does this). So having an address there too appears needed with proxy ARP. Beside,there's no way to not waste the zero and broadcast addresses:that's because the routers consider 129.212.157.200/29 and 129.212.175.24/29 as LAN routes.Had the provider given two (even private) additional addresses for routing purpose, then 2x8 would have been available. 2x4 separate remain (+ some reuse with NAT).

Comment: Last but not least: if the host provider doesn't have restrictions with MAC addresses, then using a *single* real bridge could be easier than proxy ARP (you can still use a firewall when needed) with 2 bridges not completely used as bridges.